# How to divide two TextBoxes with a double and a int?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, type-conversion

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int res = 0;
    try
    {
        res = Convert.ToInt32(costot.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(unidadesp.Text);
        costou.Text = res.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to perform a non-integer division in VB.Net? Anyway, this is also not working in C#: the result should be a decimal value. If I interpret it correctly, you are trying to divide a *Total Value* by the *Number of Units*, which returns a decimal type. But, you shouldn't do this kind of operations. If you have an *Unit Value/Price*, then you should multiply it by the number of units, not derive the unit *value*. You'll have, quite possibly, a form of rounding, so, at some point, values won't match anymore...

Comment: Also, you should use `decimal.TryParse()` and `int.TryParse()` here (the same in VB.Net), since the *values* come from TextBoxes. You can never be sure what you get from a User input. Possibly, use NumericUpDown controls to help in validating this input. Then, you have to consider the CurrentCulture when formatting the result. Different cultures have different thousand/decimal separators and number of decimal places when, for example, you have to represent currency (the currency symbol may be needed, too).

Comment: Also, check for 0 in the denominator.

Comment: Thank's for the responses... I know it wasn't a good question. Anyway, the dividend comes from a database in decimal data type (7000,50) , and the divisor is a direct input by the client (500). We have to divide those values 7000,50/500 = 14,001 and show it in a textbox when a click event occurs.

Comment: we are using this code:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            int res = 0;
           

            res = Convert.ToDouble(costot.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(unidadesp.Text);
            costou.Text = res.ToString();      
            




        }

we've tried the decimal.TryParse() and int.TryParse() and we are looking for the correct syntaxis.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after but it should give you the syntax.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int res = 0;
        if (double.TryParse(costot.Text, out double costot) && double.TryParse(unidadesp.Text, out double unidadesp) && unidadesp != 0)
        {
            res = (int)(Math.Round(costot / unidadesp));
            costou.Text = res.ToString();
        }
    }
```

If you need the costot and unidadesp both changed to Integers before the division then do this.

```
res = (int)(Math.Round(Math.Round(costot) / Math.Round(unidadesp)));
```

One more edit

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out double costot) && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out int unidadesp) && unidadesp != 0)
        {
           var res = costot / unidadesp;
            textBox3.Text = res.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use an `int` here. The result, as the OP described, should be as in the example:  `7000,50/500 = 14,001`. Because of the `7000,50` input (not a `decimal` nor a `double`, it's just a formatted string), you need two `decimal` types and return a `decimal`.

Comment: @Jimi As long as culture is set to a location where the coma is the decimal separator won't double.TryParse("7000,50", out double dbl) work?

Comment: Check the rounding. That's not the only issue. This is another: `res = (int)(costot / unidadesp);`. You need to return/generate a decimal here, not an int. See the example.

Comment: @Jimi I thought they wanted an int since res is declared as int. Now I see they want to convert the numbers before the division. BTW I have added Math.Round.

Comment: @Jimi I hope my edits to my answer have gotten a bit closer to what the OP needs.

Comment: `string totalS = "7000,50"; string partsS = "500"; decimal.TryParse(totalS, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, new CultureInfo("es-EC"), out decimal total);
decimal.TryParse(partsS, out decimal parts); decimal result = total / parts;`. Now,  `result = 14.001M`, as the OP comment about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014948/how-to-divide-two-textboxes-with-a-double-and-a-int/60019689?noredirect=1#comment106145422_60014948). Add the missing `if`s.

Comment: Just set my decimal character as a coma. Seems to work fine now.

Comment: Does your System have a comma as decimal separator? If it does not, when you `double.TryParse()` this: `"7000,50"`, you get this: `700050`, which is an integer stored in a floating point struct. When you divide by `"500"`, you get `1400.1`: not the required `14.001`, which will then be presented as the expected `"14,001"` when formatted in an `"es"` culture. So, you need to specify a culture that uses that separator, as in `decimal.TryParse([string], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, new CultureInfo("es"), out decimal [value])`. Since a decimal representation is expected, use all decimal types.

Comment: I've used `new CultureInfo("es-EC")` before and `new CultureInfo("es")` now (same type of decimal representation) because the OP is from Ecuador, so this reproduces the separator types used in that culture. When parsing strings representing numeric values, the CultureInfo that produced the format needs to be replicated.

Comment: @Jimi I set my decimal separate to a comma in Windows 10 settings temporarily so, I could test my code. The code worked using 7000,50 in the text box and produced 14,001 in the result text box.

Comment: You shouldn't modify your System configuration to parse a string :) You need to use an explicit `CultureInfo`. You don't know in what System this code will run. You just know what the input format is (because it's been provided). The OP implementation is responsible for detecting/identifying the correct culture settings that formatted the input string. It might be `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, or not. Your code just needs to use a `TryParse()` overload that allows to specify the CultureInfo settings. You can omit it only when the local CultureInfo format is implied (here, it's not).

Comment: @Jimi Got it. Thank you.